# Augmented reality - a poster on a wall

Tags: android, augmented-reality

How to implement casting a poster (or a painting) on a wall (in camera window)? Proper perspective must be implemented, as the camera can be pointed at various angles to the wall. Can anyone guide me to a solution or an example please?
I am thinking about using some free SDK like EasyAR, but not necessarily the one. Thanks.

Comment: Try Vuforia SDK. They have tons examples on how to do that

Comment: Are you considering marker tracking?

Comment: Yes I am. Seems like there is practically no other way.  I guess hanging a piece of paper with a mark or a QR code print on the wall would do the trick.